# Make php DatetTime class from the format like `22-Sep-17`

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to make PHP DateTime class from these format

`22-Sep-17`
 `18-Aug-17`

I am trying to do something like this but, Sep, Aug is a bit unique to handle.

How can I do this??

```
 $format = 'd-m-y';
 $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '22-Sep-17');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: How is this a typo? The user didn't know the difference between `m` and `M`, that doesn't make it a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is the format character for the month numerically. What you need is `M`, which returns a 3 letters abbreviation of the month.

```
<?php
$format = 'd-M-y';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '22-Sep-17');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

See all the formats [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Je0Xd)